# SCORM 2004 - setting completion for SCO from inside another SCO

Tags: scorm2004, completion

Is there a SCORM call I can use to set completion by target of a SCO?  The call would be made on a SCO different from the one getting a completion call.

Something like SetValue("cmi.completion_status","completed") combined with "{target=}" ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer no, however if you had this within a module/lesson you could structure your rollup rules to meet objectives.  This would take more advantage of the Sequence & Navigation spec of SCORM 2004 (which is a lot of reading).
Another thing you could use in limited capacity is Shared State Persistence (SSP) which was a bolt-on to SCORM and has limited support on LMS Systems.  It enables you to set a bucket id to share data between SCOs.